# Is the intersection of finite codimensional subspaces of finite codimension in an infinite dim vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

is the intersection of finite codimensional subspaces of finite codimension in an infinite dim vector space?

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional vector space, with subspaces $V,W$ such that $\dim X/V,\dim X/W<\infty$. I want to know if $\dim X/(V\cap W)<\infty$. I want to say it is true, but am having trouble proving this.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, $(V+W)/W\cong V/(V\cap W)$, that’s one of the Isomorphism Theorems. Since the left-hand side is finite-dimensional, so is the right. Then you have the inclusions $V\cap W\subset V\subset X$. Both the quotients here are finite-dimensional, so the all-the-way quotient $X/(V\cap W)$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: Could you add some explanation, to end of your proof? I don't understand, why last sentence is true.

Answer (score 1):

Tacet - The result follows from the third isomorphism theorem. If $V/(V \cap W)$ and $X/V$ are finite dimensional, then dim $X/(V \cap W) < \infty$ (otherwise, you could use the first isomorphism theorem to preposterously write dim $X/(V \cap W)$ as a sum of finite ordinals)

Comment: This seems to be almost exactly the same as Lubin's answer.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Actually, this seems to be a reaction to Tacet's comment by somebody who doesn't have enough reputation to comment...

Comment: @JossevanDobbendeBruyn: You're correct. I don't know how I missed that.