# Finite dimensional containment

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space. Tate defines, in his famous paper "Residues of differentials on curves." a relation $A \leq B$ on subspaces of $V$ meaning $A \subseteq B+W$ for $W$ finite dimensional. Tate claims that if $A \leq B$ and $A\leq B'$ then $A \leq B\cap B'.$ I do not see how to prove this, and Tate does not. Can anyone give an argument?

My current attempt is to write $A \subseteq B +W$ and $A \subseteq B' + W'$ where $B\cap W = B'\cap W' = 0$ and $W, W'$ are finite dimensional. Then $A \subseteq (B+W)\cap (B'+W').$ But I can't see how to relate this intersection to anything involving a $B\cap B'.$

Comment: Why assume that $B$ is finite-dimensional? In that case $A \le 0$ and the argument is easy.

Comment: A proof of the $A = V$ case can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574224/is-the-intersection-of-finite-codimensional-subspaces-of-finite-codimension-in-a). Note: a subspace $B$ of $V$ is said to have *finite codimension* if $V \le B$. You could try adapting this proof for the more general case.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Sorry, I meant $W, W'$ finite